# Update MySQL data using a .bat file

Tags: mysql, batch-file, command-line

I want to create an easy way of updating client's MySQL databases by sending them a file or files that they can run to make changes to their database whenever I have an application update that requires additional columns or new tables. I have followed a few threads here and below is what I have so far but when I run it, it doesn't do anything. So I have a .bat file that is meant to execute a command in another file I named "script.txt"

This is what I have in my batch file:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysql.exe -hlocalhost -uroot -pMyPassword pc < C:\Users\Public\pc\script.txt
```

And in the `script.txt` file the batch file is calling, I have the following command:

```
USE `myDataBase`; 
ALTER TABLE `myDataBase`.`myTable`
ADD COLUMN `myNewColumn` VARCHAR(45) NULL AFTER `myExistingColumn`;
```

Comment: have you run this in a command prompt window to see if you get any output? What about if you run the command by itself directly in the command window (not from the batch file)? Try to narrow down the problem. P.S. By giving this file to your users you are effectively handing over root access to the database to them...consider whether that's really something you want to do...or not! If they already have root access to their instance, then fine, but otherwise consider if you could take a different approach to this.

Comment: Very important point ADyson. The idea is to run this bat file on application startup (if it exists), if not, I ignore. Then once I run it, I delete it. But of course they will still have a copy from the email or however I sent it to them. Do you have any other ideas regarding how to achieve this without have to visit or remotely logon to each client's server whenever I alter the database? How is this typically done, when one has several clients all over the place

Comment: remote logon would be the normal way, to be honest. Or you deliver them an executable with the credentials hard-coded in, which is hard/impossible to decompile or decrypt. And if you start providing SAAS in the cloud instead of giving users an on-premises database to host themselves, then this kind of problem just disappears entirely.

Comment: Using an executable makes absolute sense, at least, till I start using cloud databases. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems good to me, you just have to put quotes around the path and executable.

Try:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysql.exe" -hlocalhost -uroot -pMyPassword pc < C:\Users\Public\pc\script.txt
```

Note if your input file has space in it's path/name, you should quote it too.